Android check if google is login on your device
Currently l'm working on intergrate passkeys on Android.
How can l check if the device is login google account?
If the device not login google account how can i swich to login google my google account on device?
Google sign in always requires serverId, but l do not need to signIn google to my app just sign in on my device.
l try to use GoogleSignIn
val googleIdOption: GetGoogleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
  .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true)
  .setServerClientId(WEB_CLIENT_ID)
  .setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
  .setNonce(<nonce string to use when generating a Google ID token>)
  .build()

But it always needs WEB_CLIENT_ID, don't know the WEB_CLIENT_ID since l'm not using google sign in to my app.
